# How to use app.debug in Flask app deployed on Azure?

Tags: python, azure, debugging, flask

I've created a simple Flask app using Azure, which I git cloned and modified to enable debug mode - my `__init.py__` now looks like:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)
app.debug = True

import FlaskWebProject1.views
```

And then made it throw a server error, in the project's `views.py`:

```
def bad_method():
    return 1/0

@app.route('/')
def home():
    """Renders the home page."""

    a = bad_method()

    return render_template(...) # Never gets here
```

When I run this locally using the development server (`runserver.py`), I get a useful stacktrace in the console and also in the browser - this is what I want.

When I push the code up to Azure and visit the deployed site I get a plain `The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred.` 500 Error, with no stacktrace shown in the browser.

Is there a way that I can enable the same debug mode while developing that I have locally when my code is deployed in Azure? The stack trace in a log would be OK, but in the browser would be far better.

EDIT: I've modified my views to pass through `app.debug` to a template, and it shows as True. So this must be Azure somehow hiding the stack trace?

Comment: Callum, did you ever figure this out?

Comment: Not really - I found that the log files are available in the Kudu console though. I don't remember if this was using the Flask app from Azure or a plain Python web app - but I found that using the Flask app from Azure I couldn't really get anything working correctly. A support person advised me to use a custom deployment script etc from their blog: https://prmadi.com/running-flask-app-with-httpplatformhandler-in-azure-app-services/ - and with that I get the logs in the Kudu console.